# Recieving broken attachments from webform to cpanel webmail

Tags: php, webforms, base64, mime, webmail

I have a simple web form on my site, which requests a few fields of data from the user;

Name, Email and Message, as well as an image file.

For a few years, everything seemed to work smoothly with a gmail account set as the receiving email address.

However... recently, with no changes made to the code at all, the emails started coming in very slowly, and sometimes not at all.

Out of frustration, I created a webmail account with Roundcube through my cPanel, to receive the form submissions.

After testing, the submissions are showing up consistently now and very fast. I receive all of the texts portions of the data, every time.

That's the good news.

That bad news is that attachments (images) are broken. I receive a displayed outline of the image which shows the correct image name and file extension, but the file size shows '0' and the actual image is not displayed.

I can even 'download' the broken image, but even then, the file size is still '0' and still cannot be displayed.

Again... I haven't changed anything in the code except the recipient email address, from a gmail account to the webmail account.

When I used the very same code with gmail, the images always came in just fine.

I was on the phone with my hosting tech support last night for about 2 hours and we checked many things on the server side, including some Roundcube settings, such as; 'Always display images in message' etc...

We had no luck solving the mystery.

Can anyone recognize anything in this code which may cause the images to come in broken specifically in webmail?

Or if the code is in order, perhaps some other suggestions as to why this is happening?

Any help is appreciated... thank you.

```
<?php

$fileName =  $_FILES['userImages']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userImages']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_POST['userName'];
$email = $_POST['userEmail'];
$message = $_POST['userMessage'];

$composition =

"\r\n\n\nName: "                        . $name .
"\r\nEmail Address: "                   . $email .
"\r\n\n\nMessage: "                     . $message;

$subject ="User Message";

$fromname ="$name";
$fromemail = "$email";

$mailto = 'reciepient@receivingaddress.com';

$content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$separator = md5(time());

$eol = "\r\n";

$headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
$body .= $composition . $eol;

$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $fileName . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

@mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

header('location: /sent_confirmation_page.html');

?>
```

Comment: Tthe images file extension (JPG, PNG, etc) might be missing maybe.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I considered there may be an issue with the extension not making the journey. But the broken image imprint, which is displayed in the message, does contain the file name as well as the extension. So I assumed the extension was carried through. Or am I assuming too much?

Comment: If you search SO for questions about PHP and mail attachments, you'll find the same advice repeated ad infinitum - don't do it manually, just use a library to handle it all for you.  I understand the itch to work out why it stopped working, and what the problem is, but with fiddly stuff like MIME header attachment syntax  ... how much do you really care? :-) Here's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail One observation - using `@mail` suppresses any errors that might be telling you about any problems, remove the `@` when you're bug hunting.